# Выбор определенных файлов на флешке без использования OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

У нас имеется флешка, требуется вывести в программу все доступные файлы определенного типа (допустим doc, txt) и, при этом, флешки могут отличаться наименованиями. Как это сделать без использования OpenFileDialog?

Comment: Флешки могут монтироваться на разные драйвы? Есть какая метка что это искомая флешка?

Comment: Всего одна флешка, а название может быть абсолютно случайно

Comment: Корневой путь к флешке вы планируете задавать сами?

Comment: Он должен автономно определятся, конечно если есть такая возможность.

Comment: DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList(); + Directory.GetFiles()

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev может ответом оформите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList();
+
Directory.GetFiles()
```

Comment: Может объясните в ответе, почему это должно работать? Ато человеку неясно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704227/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0