# Попрошу вас объяснить кусочек кода

Tags: c#, wpf

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList();
+
Directory.GetFiles()
```

Comment: Первая получает список дисков, потом отбирает из него диски с типом `Removable`, т.е. съемные. Вторая - список файлов в папке. Рекомендую в студии выделять непонятные слова и нажимать F1, что откроет MSDN по выбранному методу/свойству/константе/перемещению.

Comment: Что ж вы сразу не попросили расписать подробнее, там где вам такой ответ дали?

Comment: Тут я этого не знаю, моя глупость)

Comment: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697868/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-openfiledialog?noredirect=1#comment1034568_697868)

Comment: Ну так снимите там галочку и попросите расписать подробнее, а этот вопрос закройте

Comment: В коде три класса, четыре метода и два свойства. Какую именно часть нужно объяснить? Если вопросов более одного, то лучше задавать их по одному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Это последовательный вызов методов
   `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` - получает список дисков
   `.Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)`  - Linq- запрос, перечисляющий элементы с заданным условием:
   `x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable` - условие выборки: выбрать только те диски в которых DriveType == DriveType.Removable, то есть съемные диски
   `ToList()` -  преобразовать отобранную коллекцию в `List`

2.

```
Directory.GetFiles()
```

Вызов статического метода `GetFiles()` класса `Directory`
Возвращает массив строк.
Подробнее о классе и его методах, в том числе различных перегрузках  `GetFiles()` смотри [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: поправка: не `возвращающий коллекцию по заданному условию`, а `перечисляющий элементы с заданным условием`. Отложенное вычисление - это основная фишка Linq и это же источник большинства граблей. Считаю, что в данном случае, так как автор не понимает конструкции, не стоит подменять понятия, чтобы он не наделал ошибок в будущем.